# How to add OpenWith and SaveAs Dialogue Box while generating pdf from jasper

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

Hii Guys!!!
              I generated a simple parametrised jasper report for exporting data into pdf formate.Now As per my code pdf file is generating and opening by downloading automatically whereas i need Saveas Dialogue Box to ask for openwith or saveas ...Any suggestions will be appreciated...Thanx in advance..Here is my code ...

```
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
InputStream reportStream = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("para.jasper");
try {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    System.out.println(name);
    String query = "Select * from vikas where vikas.name='" + name + "'";
    System.out.println(query);
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/techsoft?user=root&password=techsoft");
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
    JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(resultSet);
    JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream, new HashMap(), resultSetDataSource);
    resultSet.close();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
    servletOutputStream.flush();
    servletOutputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the [`Content-Disposition` http header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html). Also add the `Content-Type`

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + getFileName() + "\"");
```

Comment: And note that you depend of the browser managing it correctly. I think most major browsers do, but if the one you use does not there is nothing to do.